# How can I use HttpClient-4.5 against a SOCKS proxy?

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

How can I use a ClosableHttpClient from [HttpClient-4.5](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/) over a configured SOCKS proxy? Is there a way to accomplish this without specifying a global SOCKS proxy with `java -DsocksProxyHost` or setting a custom default `ProxySelector`?

The [explicit documention about proxies](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e485), is as far as I understand only about HTTP proxies (which I imply by defining such a proxy as `HttpHost`). For me it looks like ["Connection socket factories"](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e431) is more relevant.