# How to use a socks proxy with Java JDK HttpClient

Tags: java, proxy, socks, java-http-client

> ***NOTE:*** This is not a duplicate of [https proxy with JDK11 client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63716442/https-proxy-with-jdk11-client), which is about a HTTP proxy. My question is about a socks proxy, which requires a different solution. Neither is it a duplicate of [How can I use HttpClient-4.5 against a SOCKS proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43292049/how-can-i-use-httpclient-4-5-against-a-socks-proxy), which is about the Apache HttpClient instead of the JDK HttpClient.

How can I use a socks 5 proxy with `java.net.http.HttpClient`?

I tried the code below, but it results in a following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: HTTP/1.1 header parser received no bytes
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:586)
```

Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class ProxyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        run1();
    }

    public static void run1() throws Exception {
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
                .proxy(ProxySelector.of(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8181)))
                .build();

        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest
                .newBuilder(new URI("http://example.org/"))
                .build();
        HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        String verificationText = "Example Domain";
        // Should print "true" otherwise the request failed
        System.out.println(response.body().contains(verificationText));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Problem 1: JDK HttpClient doesn't support socks proxies

JDK HttpClient doesn't support socks proxies, only HTTP(S) proxies, even though types like `java.net.Proxy.Type.SOCKS` do exist. This problem isn't documented at all in the Java JDK, which causes Java to silently disregard the socks proxy when you try to use it, by using a non-proxy connection.

This problem is reported as a bug in 2018 to OpenJDK, but hasn't been fixed yet: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8214516
The code that is responsible for this silent disregard is:
https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/29e552c03a2825f9526330072668a1d63ac68fd4/src/java.net.http/share/classes/jdk/internal/net/http/HttpRequestImpl.java#L299

```
    private static Proxy retrieveProxy(ProxySelector ps, URI uri) {
        Proxy proxy = null;
        List<Proxy> pl = ps.select(uri);
        if (!pl.isEmpty()) {
            Proxy p = pl.get(0);
            if (p.type() == Proxy.Type.HTTP)
                proxy = p;
        }
        return proxy;
    }
```

So if the ProxySelector provides a `Proxy` with type `Proxy.Type.SOCKS` as first proxy, then it is ignored, and `null` is returned, which causes HttpRequestImpl to not use a proxy at all.

## Problem 2: Unclear API

Even if the missing JDK implementation problem would be solved, then there is also an API problem in unclarity:

The unclarity problem is caused by `java.net.ProxySelector.of(InetSocketAddress)`, which doesn't document what kind of proxy it creates. A proxy can either be a web (http) proxy or a socks proxy. The source code of `ProxySelector.of()` shows that it creates a private StaticProxySelector object, which creates a web proxy (`Proxy.Type.HTTP`) instead of a socks proxy (`Proxy.Type.SOCKS`).

So the solution (if the JDK internal code would be fixed) is to create your own ProxySelector. This is shown in the solution below.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class ProxyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        run2();
    }

    public static void run2() throws Exception {
        ProxySelector proxySelector = new ProxySelector() {
            private List<Proxy> proxies;

            {
                Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8181));
                proxies = Collections.singletonList(proxy);
            }

            @Override
            public List<Proxy> select(URI uri) {
                return proxies;
            }

            @Override
            public void connectFailed(URI uri, SocketAddress sa, IOException ioe) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
            }
        };

        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
                .proxy(proxySelector)
                .build();

        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest
                .newBuilder(new URI("http://example.org/"))
                .build();
        HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        String verificationText = "Example Domain";
        // Should print "true" otherwise the request failed
        System.out.println(response.body().contains(verificationText));
    }
}
```